# Oracle number data type

Tags: oracle

Can anyone explain the oracle number data type: salary number(*,*)

Comment: There is no such thing as number(,) - at least in oracle 10g

Comment: Looks like the result of a (misguided) query like this: `select table_name || ' ' || data_type || '(' || data_precision || ',' || data_scale || ')' from user_tab_columns`

Answer (score 3):

The folks at Oracle do a pretty good job of explaining it.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3810

Is there anything in particular that you are looking for?